# How to pass props through window.href react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have passed props through to different components and pages before but this has been through link or just added these to the component tag itself.

The issue I have here is that the redirect is not going through a link tag or in a component tag and instead I am simply using window.locatio.href ="whatever the url is".

I simply want to pass a variable through to this (I am technically doing a refresh in this situation so window.location.reload() could also work if it is possible).

How would I pass through a variable within this. 
When using express you can do fetch statements with an endpoint simialr to (might not be exact syntax) "./page${variableYouWant}" Then access sit in the express file using req.params.variableYouWant.

Is this possible to pass a variable this way and how would I then access it.

Here is the most important snippet of my code.

```
pageRelocator(mssg) {
    if (mssg.length < 35) {
      toast.info(`${mssg}`, {

        draggable: true,

        autoClose: 1500
      });
      window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/completed-assessment";
    } else if (mssg.length > 35) {
      toast.error(`${mssg}`, {

        draggable: true,

        autoClose: 1500
      });
//Here I would like to pass a variable
      window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/user-questions";
    }
  }
```

EDIT--

```
componentDidMount() {
    const search = this.props.location.mssg;
    alert(search); // returns the URL query String
    const params = new URLSearchParams(search);
    const IdFromURL = params.get("mssg");

    this.setState({
      questions: this.getItems(),
      WorkStations: this.getWorkStations()
    });
  }
  pageRelocator(mssg) {
    if (mssg.length < 35) {
      window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/completed-assessment";
    } else if (mssg.length > 35) {
      window.location.href = `http://localhost:3000/user-questions?mssg=${mssg}`;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

Try using the `URLSearchParams` which defines utility methods to work with the query string of URL.so to attach a variable you would do

```
var id=5;
window.location.href = `http://localhost:3000/user-questions?id=${id}`;
```

and to retreive id from the URL you would do

```
const search = props.location.search; // returns the URL query String
const params = new URLSearchParams(search); 
const IdFromURL = params.get('id');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: No this is through the front end

Comment: i have updated the code , see if this works for you

Comment: Thanks ! I am getting "Cannot read property 'search' of undefined"

Comment: I am using a class component if that helps and am using this in component did mount

Comment: could you post the code of the component you are trying to use this in? or provide a `codepen` or `codesandbox`

Comment: I essentially want when the page refreshed to carry over the mssg

Comment: `this.props.location` has an object called `search` so it should be  `this.props.location.search` not `this.props.location.mssg`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209577/discussion-between-abdullah-abid-and-henry-pf).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data to be present even after refresh, try to pass the variable in params. 
`http://localhost:3000/completed-assessment?your_variable=value`
If you want to use this params value you can use 
`window.location.search`
Using `URLSearchParams` you can get the each params you've sent with the URL. 
Please refer https://www.sitepoint.com/get-url-parameters-with-javascript/ for more info